# I cannot set value to the variable globally defined while firing on change event in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let rows;

let defaultValue = 10;

function RowChange(id, tableId) {
    const select = document.getElementById(id);

    var targetTable = "#" + tableId;
    select.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
        rows = event.target.value;

        $(targetTable + `> tbody > tr`).hide().slice(0, rows).show();
        Paginate("tableId", rows)
    });
}
console.log(rows);
```

```
 RowChange("rowSelect", "MenuSetup");
```

Here console.log(rows) is  undefined but inside that function it has value.

Comment: First add alert in the RowChange function as well as above `rows = event.target.value;`, If the not fired on second time, then add debug near the alert.  then run and debug the code. Some how this error shows that you select event not fired.

Comment: You aren't executing `RowChange()` and even if you did, you'd also need to trigger the _change_ event on the id'd element before `rows` was assigned any value

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the execution order of JS (and really any other language).

The JavaScript runtime interpreter is going to do the following things (in order)

1. Define a variable `rows` that is undefined in value.
2. Define a variable `defaultValue` that has value `10`.
3. Define a function `RowChange` that performs some behavior *when called* but importantly *it's not going to call the function right away* so you setting the value of `rows` in the function does nothing at this point.
4. Console log `rows` which *is still undefined* because you haven't actually called `RowChange`

Edit: And as @Phil pointed out in his comment, the row change is actually occurring inside the change handler you define inside the function.

Edit 2:

This is the sequence of events that would need to happen for your code *as written* to have the effect you're expecting (keep in mind that I'm not saying this is optimal or stylistically good code)

```js
let rows;

let defaultValue = 10;

function RowChange(id, tableId) {
    const select = document.getElementById(id);

    var targetTable = "#" + tableId;
    select.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
        rows = event.target.value;

        $(targetTable + `> tbody > tr`).hide().slice(0, rows).show();
        Paginate("tableId", rows)
    });
}
const rowID = 'rowSelect';

// call the RowChange function to bind the onChange event listener 
// to rowSelect
RowChange(rowID, "MenuSetup");

const selectElement = document.getElementById(rowID);
const event = new Event('change'); 

// programmatically forcing a change event to be fired, causing the
// event listener to fire the handleChange callback.
selectElement.dispatchEvent(event);

// now it will be what you expect it to be
console.log(rows);
```

Comment: sorry, I havent added code that is calling rowChange function, I have edit my question!. @pedro

Comment: As @Phil pointed out,  Calling `RowChange('rowSelect', 'MenuSetup')` is insufficient because the actual change to rows is happening in the followup change event handler you bind inside of the `RowChange` function. I'll edit my comment with the list of things that would need to happen for the code *as written* to produce the change you're expecting.

Comment: is there anyway, that I can set variable to when function on change is called without repeating .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question as written. Could you rephrase that? Did you mean "is there some way to have the variable set without having to call RowChange, then dispatch an onchange event"?

Comment: let rowss;
const rowChange=(rows)=>{
rowss=rows;
} here function is not changing global variable when called as rowChange(20);

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0jxa7c6k/) is an example of it working

Comment: Problem is here is it is on two different files. function is on different file and function is calling on the html page where script is embedded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250510/discussion-between-sumitkhatrii-and-pedro-del-moral-lopez).